# Is it possible to insert elements to BST with complexity lower than O(n) worst case?

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Given the following algorithm for inserting elements into BST :

```
 void InsertNode(Node* &treeNode, Node *newNode)
 {
     if (treeNode == NULL)
       treeNode = newNode;
     else if (newNode->key < treeNode->key)
       InsertNode(treeNode->left, newNode);
     else
       InsertNode(treeNode->right, newNode);
 }
```

This algorithm runs in `O(n)` worst case .

Is it possible to insert elements into a BST using an algorithm with a lower complexity then `O(n)` , in the worst case ?

**Remark 1** : This is not homework (preparing for an upcoming exam)

**Remark 2** : without using `AVL` trees

Thanks

Comment: If you exclude the possibility of a balanced binary search tree, then you allow for the possibility of a tree that is a single branch, which is exactly the `O(n)` case.  So no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The insert is equivalent to a search operation.  Clearly if your tree is not balanced, the worst-case will always be a tree in the form of a linked-list.  So there is no way to avoid the O(n).